# How to generate int array of 256 values inside?

Tags: c#

csharp generate random int[] of 256 values inside each value to be randomly from 1 to 1000

so when I put the mouse on the array with a breakpoint I will see 256 values and each value will be random number from 1 to 1000.

```
int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

this will generate array of 5 places with the values 1,2,3,4,5
now I want to make the same array with 256 places and each one instead 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....each number to be random between 1 to 1000.

Comment: Why down vote? the solution is not right?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would be surprised if you can't already find a dozen different answers to almost the same question as yours. Yours doesn't really show any research attempt. Your answer is a code-only answer which doesn't explain what it's doing, so it could be hard to follow for new programmers. I expect the trivial nature of the question combined with it being a perennial question makes your ask/self-answer seem like an attempt to garner reputation rather than a serious attempt to help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need code without classes?

```
Random rnd = new Random(); // declaring a variable of the "Random" class that gives us the ability to generate random numbers
int[] array = new int[256]; // standard way to create an array
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = rnd.Next(1, 1001); //1001 -> because the upper limit of the returned random number is not included in the generated numbers themselves
}
```

Comment: If I made mistakes in English, I'm sorry, I haven't fully mastered it yet

Answer (score -1):

solution

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int[] test = new int[256];
            for(int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {
                
                test[i] = r.Next(1, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
```